# Cannot read property 'Workbook' of undefined$.ig.GridExcelExporter.$.ig.GridExcelExporter

Tags: javascript, ignite-ui

I am using ignite ui hierarchical grid and in my $.ig.loader i have the following code

```
scriptPath: "http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/",
cssPath: "http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/",
resources: 'igHierarchicalGrid,'+
'modules/infragistics.documents.core.js,' +
'modules/infragistics.excel.js,' +
'modules/infragistics.gridexcelexporter.js'
```

My export click event has the following code

```js
$.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid($("#hierarchicalGrid"), {
           dataExportMode: $("#dataExportMode").val(),
           type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
          });
```

I tried the various combinations but however I am unable to the run the export code.
After executing i am getting

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Workbook' of undefined$.ig.GridExcelExporter.$.ig.GridExcelExporter.Class.extend._createExcelWorkbookWithWorksheet @ infragistics.gridexcelexporter.js:23(anonymous function) @ infragistics.gridexcelexporter.js:23

P.S : cannot provide the code of Hierarchical Grid due to confidentiality & that part is working perfectly. Only export is not working.

Comment: Are there other errors before this happens? Because your code is pretty much standard and the exception means essentially the `$.ig.excel` namepsace is undefined as if the infragistics.excel.js module failed to load, yet it does load right here: http://jsfiddle.net/damyanpetev/8cn284mu/ 
There must be something else causing an issue outside this configuration.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. Actually if you use $.ig.GridExcelExporter.export rather than the $.ig.GridExcelExporter.exportGrid method it works.

Comment: The method name was called "export" only in the first version of the igGridExcelExporter , which was introduced with IgniteUI 15.1 With 15.2 it was renamed to "exportGrid"